# Наименьшая библиотека C/C++ для редактирования изображений

Tags: c++, linux, c, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая самая маленькая библиотека C/C++ для редактирования изображений? Чтобы можно было вставлять в изображения по `x` и `y` текст, что-то типа приложения [convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). Желательно размер меньше 1 мегабайта.

Upd1:

Нашёл [вот такую](https://cimg.eu/reference/index.html) библиотеку. Вполне выполняет всё, что необходимо. Скомпилированный вариант весит порядка 700-800 килобайт. Если есть варианты ещё проще, прошу поделиться.

Upd2:

Оказывается, что под капотом библиотека юзает gm и convert. Там, где я хотел применить программу, собранную на основе данной библиотеки мне выдало:

```
sh: convert: not found
sh: gm: not found
```

Так что - библиотека не самостоятельная.

Comment: Вам на самом деле нужно три "кусочка". код, который будет распаковывать картинку в массив пикселей, код, который делает обратную операцию и третий код, который будет собственно "вставлять" картинку. Первые два куска зависят от того, какие форматы Вам нужны. третий кусок можно очень просто написать самому ручками. в принципе, stb_image должна решить все.

Comment: @KoVadim да, мне по факту нужно загрузить изображение в формате jpeg, потом "вставить" туда текст и сохранить всё, что получилось.

Comment: для текста в stb есть готовые функции.

Comment: @KoVadim Сложновато.. Что-то не пойму, как вообще туда текст вставлять.